# displot does not show part of the title and xlabel

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, displot

This is a snippet of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

filename = 'MY_FILENAME_GOES_HERE'

enctimes=pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=10)

sns.displot(enctimes,kde=True, legend=False, bins=bins).set(title='Encoding Times  %s, number frames %d' %(fileForTitle,len(enctimes)),xlabel='usec')

plt.show()
```

Why does it cut off the title and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Probably your canvas size is too small.

Comment: Did you try `plt.tight_layout()`?

Comment: enctimes=pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=10)
    sns.displot(enctimes,kde=True, legend=False, bins=bins).set(title='Encoding Times  %s, number frames %d' %(fileForTitle,len(enctimes)),xlabel='usec')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plt.tight_layout` (see [Tight Layout guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)) to fit the title automatically. Here is a sample edit of your code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

enctimes = np.random.normal(size=840)
bins = 30
title = 'Encoding Times %s, number frames %d' % ('fileForTitle', len(enctimes))
sns.displot(enctimes, kde=True, legend=False, bins=bins).set(title=title, xlabel='usec')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Executing this will output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

JohanC recommended to use "plt.tight_layout()", i added this function before    plt.show() and now the title is not cut

[image]